# The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion in C#

Tags: c#, service, windows-services

I created windows service in .net framework 4 with c#. I installed it to services sucessfully. But when I trying to start it it says that **" The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"**

Here is my code

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        private Service_Bll objService_Bll = new Service_Bll();

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        System.Timers.Timer timer;
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            this.WriteToFile("Simple Service started {0}");
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.InitTimer));
            t.Start();
        }

        private void InitTimer()
        {
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            //wire up the timer event 
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            //set timer interval   
            //var timeInSeconds = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimerIntervalInSeconds"]); 
            timer.Interval = (10 * 1000);
            // timer.Interval is in milliseconds, so times above by 1000 
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }


        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            this.WriteToFile("Simple Service stopped {0}");
        }


        private void WriteToFile(string text)
        {
            string path = "C:\\ServiceLog.txt";
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(string.Format(text, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")));
                writer.Close();
            }
        }




        public void ScheduleService()
        {
            try
            {
                objService_Bll.UpdateAccessDetails();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToFile("Simple Service Error on: {0} " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);

                //Stop the Windows Service.
                using (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController serviceController = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("Service1"))
                {
                    serviceController.Stop();
                }
            }
        }

        protected void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.WriteToFile("Simple Service run {0}");
            ScheduleService();
        }

    }
```

Here is the intilizecomponent()

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
        this.serviceInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
        // 
        // serviceProcessInstaller1
        // 
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = null;
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = null;
        // 
        // serviceInstaller1
        // 
        this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName = "Service1";
        this.serviceInstaller1.StartType = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
        // 
        // ProjectInstaller
        // 
        this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[] {
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1,
        this.serviceInstaller1});

    }
```

I cant figure this. Please help. Thank you very much.

Comment: are you using release build?

Comment: Try Both. One SO thread said that I should use Release. Tried. But Failed

Comment: did you try without the `this.WriteToFile("Simple Service started {0}");`

Comment: Yes. Without it also not working

Comment: how do you start the service?

Comment: By typing InstallUtil.exe "c:\myservice.exe" in visual stuio CMD in administration mode

Comment: if this is still an issue: Could you start the service, attach Visual Studio's debugger (Debug -> Attach to process...) to the service and hit 'Pause' and check what is actually going on? If you solved this already, please answer your question yourself.